# PERL CLOSING the file after slurping and "perl -0777"s translation to a complete perl file

Tags: file, perl

Inspired by the following perl one-liner `perl -0777 -ne 'while(m/YOUR_REGEX_HERE/g){print "$&\n";}' YOUR_FILE_HERE`, I am searching for the simplest way to *read an entire file into a string (a procedure also known as “slurping”)* in a complete perl file (not just a perl command), as I need to do simple operations using two files. I came around this: https://www.perl.com/article/21/2013/4/21/Read-an-entire-file-into-a-string/. (I am looking at *Slurping files without modules*.)

It suggests using

```perl
open my $fh, '<', 'text_document.txt' or die "Can't open file $!";
read $fh, my $file_content, -s $fh;
```

But how do I close the file after processing it? (1)

Also, how would that one-liner translate to a perl file, not just a perl command? (2)

Thank you!

Comment: How does this ```while(m/YOUR_REGEX_HERE/g){print "$&\n";}``` work in a complete perl file?

Comment: 1) *How do I close the file?* `close $fh`. Seemed like an obvious answer. 2) Slurping the file is only relevant if you expect your regex to match across a newline. If your regex will not cross a newline, slurping mode is irrelevant. If you want to know the code behind that one-liner, try adding the option `-MO=Deparse` to it.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the line ending special variable to be nothing within a block to keep it local. It'll be restored to the local platform's record separator after the block ends:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $contents;

{
    local $/;
    open my $fh, '<', 'file.txt' or die $!;
    $contents = <$fh>;
    close $fh;
}

print $contents;
```

Note that the bare block in the above code could be substituted with a subroutine instead.

Comment: A more common idiom for this is `my $content = do { open my $fh, '<', $file or die $!; local $/; <$fh>; };` - shorter and no need to `close` as that happens automagically when `$fh` goes out of scope.

Comment: If you could please also make it so it has the desired effect, printing "$&\n", that would be the best possible answer!

Answer (score 2):

If you want it compact, on one line:

```
my $file_content = do { local (@ARGV, $/) = $file_name; <> };
```

The [<>](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#I/O-Operators) "null" filehandle opens and reads all files with names in [@ARGV](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#Variables-related-to-filehandles) special variable.  We add `$file_name` to `@ARGV` but only after this global variable is [local](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/local)-ized, so that whatever may have been in the array is saved away and then restored once control leaves this block. Thus `<>` reads the whole file, and since it is the last command in the [do](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do) block what it read is returned.

In order to read the whole file into a string ("slurp" it) we unset the [$/](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#Variables-related-to-filehandles) special variable ("input record separator"), also after it is `local`-ized of course.