# perl add line into text file

Tags: file, perl, writefile

I am writing a script to append text file by adding some text under specific string in the file after tab spacing. Help needed to add new line and tab spacing after matched string "apple" in below case.

Example File:

```
apple
<tab_spacing>original text1
orange
<tab_spacing>original text2
```

Expected output:

```
apple
<tab_spacing>testing
<tab_spacing>original text1
orange
<tab_spacing>original text2
```

What i have tried:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $config="filename.txt";
open (CONFIG,"+<$config") or die "Fail to open config file $config\n";
    while (<CONFIG>) {
        chop;
        if (($_ =~ /^$apple$/)){
            print CONFIG "\n";
            print CONFIG "testing\n";
        }
}
      close CONFIG;
```

Comment: You should include `$!` in the error message.

Comment: How large is the file?

Comment: @zdim just a text file, will be around few kB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some pretty weird stuff in your code, to be honest:

- Reading from and writing to a file at the same time is hard. Your code, for example, would just write all over the existing data in the file
- Using a bareword filehandle (`CONFIG`) instead of a lexical variable and two-arg `open()` instead of the three-arg version (`open my $config_fh, '+<', $config'`) makes me think you're using some pretty old Perl tutorials
- Using `chop()` instead of `chomp()` makes me think you're using some ancient Perl tutorials
- You seem to have an extra `$` in your regex - `^$apple$` should probably be `^apple$`

Also, [Tie::File](https://metacpan.org/pod/Tie::File) has been included with Perl's standard library for over twenty years and would make this task far easier.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Tie::File;

tie my @file, 'Tie::File', 'filename.txt' or die $!;

for (0 .. $#file) {
  if ($file[$_] eq 'apple') {
    splice @file, $_ + 1, 0, "\ttesting\n";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

We cannot simply "add" text to a middle of a file as attempted.  A file is a sequence of bytes and one cannot add or remove them (except at the end) but only change them. So if we start writing to a middle of a file then we are changing the bytes there, so overwriting what follows that place.  Instead, we have to copy the rest of the text and write it back following the "addition," or to copy the file adding text in the process.

Yet another way is to read the whole file into a string and run a regex on it to change it, then write out the new string. Assuming that the file isn't too large for that

```
perl -0777 -pe's{apple\n\K(\t)}{Added text\n$1}g' in.txt
```

The `-0777` switch makes it read the whole file into a string ("slurp" it), available in `$_`, to which the regex is bound by default.  That `\K`, which is [a lookbehind](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#%5CK), drops previous matches so they are not consumed out of the string and we don't have to (capture and) put them back. With the `/g` [modifier](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Modifiers) it keeps going through the whole string, to find and change all occurrences of the pattern.

This prints the changed file to screen, what can be saved in a new file by redirecting it

```
perl -0777 -pe'...' in.txt > out.txt
```

Or, one can change the input file "*in place*" with `-i`

```
perl -0777 -i.bak -pe'...' in.txt
```

The `.bak` makes it save the original with `.bak` extension.  See [switches in perlrun](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun#Command-Switches).

Another way is to use a [lookahead](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind) for what follows (the tab) so that we don't have to capture and put it back

```
perl -0777 -pe's{apple\n\K(?=\t)}{Added text\n}g' in.txt
```

All of these produce the desired change.

---

**Note** on that tab ("*tab_spacing*")

The regex above assumes a tab *character* at the beginning of the line following the line with `apple`. When we say "tab" we mean one (tab) character.

But there are many reasons why there may in fact not be a tab character, even if it looks just like there is one. An example: all tabs may be automatically replaced by spaces by an editor.

So it may be safer to use `\s+` (multiple spaces) instead of `\t` in the regex

```
s{apple\n\K(\s+)}{Added text\n$1}g
```

or

```
s{apple\n\K(?=\s+)}{Added text\n}g
```

---

If this is to be done inside of an existing larger Perl program (and not as a command-line program, "one-liner," as above), one way

```
use Path::Tiny;  # path(), constructor

my $file_content = path($file)->slurp;  # read the file into a string

# Now use a regex; all discussion above applies
$file_content =~ s{apple\n\K(?=\t)}{Added text\n}g;

# Print out $file_content, to be redirected etc. Or write to a file
path($new_file)->spew($file_content);
```

I use the library [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny) to "slurp" the file into a string and `spew` to write `$file_content` to a new file.  That need be installed as it is not in a "core" (doesn't usually come installed with Perl), and if that is a problem for some strange reason here is an idiom-of-sorts for it without any libraries

```
my $file_content = do { 
    local $/;
    open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";
    <$fh>;
};
```

or even

```
my $file_content = do { local (@ARGV, $/) = $file; <> };
```

(see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66162742/4653379) for some explanation and references)

Comment: Hi, this is great info. I will try it out.

Comment: @peace  This is a fairly standard way to make changes in a file -- read the whole file into a string, let loose a regex on it, print it out.  (Or change the input file directly with `-i`).  Having a regex run on a string with the whole file makes it simpler to work with patterns that (may) span multiple lines.  The one limitation is if the file is gigantic.  But kBs is nothin'

Comment: In new versions of Perl there is `-g` for `-0777`.  [They say](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun#-g) it's for "gobble" or "gulp" (or "grab") ...

Comment: Hi @zdim, I tried your suggestion `perl -0777 -pe's{apple\n\K(?=\t)}{Added text\n}' in.txt` it works when directly execute on shell, but not in the .pl script: `system("perl -0777 -pe's{apple\n\K(?=\s+)}{testing\n}' in.txt")` Any idea?

Comment: @peace  So, this `perl ...`shown here  is meant to run in the shell.  It is a so-called "one-liner", a Perl program (between `''`) that can be executed right on the command line in the shell. But if you have a Perl program (in a file) then you can do the job directly in it -- not by going out to shell (which is what `system` does) to call another Perl program (that one-liner). In a Perl program, directly read the file, change it, and print it back out. I will add code for that to the answer when I catch a moment.

Comment: @peace  Added to the end a way to do it in an existing (presumably larger) Perl program

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what you mean by "tab spacing", but you might be looking for:

```
perl -pE 'm/^(\t*)/; say "${1}testing" if $a; $a = /apple/' filename.txt
```

I suspect you actually want `\s` instead of `\t`, but YMMV.  Basically, on each line of input, you match the leading whitespace and then print a line with that whitespace and the string 'testing' if the previous line matched.

To write it verbosely:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use 5.12.0;
use strict;
use warnings;
my $n = 'filename.txt';

open my $f, '<', $n, or die "$n: $!\n";
while(<$f>){
        m/^(\t*)/;    # possibly \s is preferred over \t
        say "${1}testing" if $a;
        $a = /apple/;
        print;
}
```

Comment: Hi, the tab spacing means using tab key on keyboard to create some spacing. You may try enter tab key in any file and you will get it.

Comment: Hi, does your code above remove the original text under apple? I would want to keep the original text, and adding new line of text under apple, with tab space

Comment: @peace, did you execute the code?  It retains all of the original content, and just inserts a single line after each line that matches `apple`.  The line that is inserted has the same initial tabs (or whitespace, depending on if you use `\t` or `\s`)  as the line that follows.  If the last line of the file matches 'apple', no additional line is added.